# How can I setup Eclipse for better Android Widget development?

Tags: eclipse, android-widget

I'm trying to develop a widget for Android. I'm using Eclipse but I can't get the view editor setup to match what I'm going to see when I deploy to my phone.

I'm creating a 4x1 widget. I've gone through and tried setting up a new "Device" so that I can preview what the widget will look like before I deploy. I said the device is landscape, setup a 240dpi for the x and y on the device and set the dimensions to 294x72 (also tried 72x294 but that didn't work any better).

I've done some googling and I can't seem to find any guides for setting up Eclipse.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what I ended up doing was just creating my main LinearLayout view to the width and height of the widget I was writing. I don't like having it so hard coded like this because if I change my widget size I have to change it in two places, but oh well. it works.